# Jquery pomodoro clock using setInterval() and clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm working on a simple pomodoro clock project using JQuery. I've gotten to where I can get the time to display and countdown the way it should but I am having issues when the timer gets to zero. I can't seem to get the clock to stop and to display 00:00 and then start the break timer. Instead I'm getting a garbage number when the timer is over. When the session time gets to 0 the clock should clear and start the break timer.

I have created a codepen for this project so you can visualize the issue. https://codepen.io/nick_kinlen/full/Bdgdqp/

```
var working = true;
var breaking = false;
var workTime = .10;
var breakTime = 32.00;
var minutes;
var seconds;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#start').click(function(){
    initializeClock('#clock', minutes, seconds);
  });

  workTime = workTime * 60;
  breakTime = breakTime * 60;
});


function initializeClock(id, minutes, seconds){
  // set up initial display of clock
  var clock = $('#clock');
  clock.text(workTime);

  // update time every second, if time is 0 stop timer
  var timeInterval = setInterval(function(){
      clock.text(minutes, seconds);

      if(working === true) {
        if(updateClock(minutes) < 0 && updateClock(seconds) < 0){
          clearInterval(timeInterval);
          working = false;
          breaking = true;
          alert('Hey this block of code is executing!');
        }
        else if(breaking === true){
          if(updateClock(minutes) === 0 && updateClock(seconds) === 0){
            clearInterval(timeInterval);
            breaking = false;
            working = true;
        }
      }
    }

  }, 1000);

}


function updateClock(time){
  // subtract time from current time,
  workTime--;

  minutes = Math.floor(workTime % 3600 / 60);
  seconds =  workTime % 60;

  // Adds a 0 in front of single digit minutes/seconds
  minutes = ('0' + minutes).slice(-2);
  seconds = ('0' + seconds).slice(-2);

  // update clock
  $('#clock').text(minutes + ':' + seconds);
  console.log(minutes, seconds);

  // If the block is on break time
  if(breaking){

    var minutes = Math.floor(breakTime % 3600 / 60);
    var seconds =  breakTime % 60;

    breakTime--;

    minutes = ('0' + minutes).slice(-2);
    seconds = ('0' + seconds).slice(-2);

    $('#clock').text(minutes + ':' + seconds);
  }

}

// Add/subtract time to break
$('#subtractBreakMinute').click(function(){
  if(breakTime > 0) {
    breakTime -= 1;
    $('#breakDisplay').text(breakTime);
  }
})

$('#addBreakMinute').click(function(){
  if(breakTime < 59) {
    breakTime += 1;
    $('#breakDisplay').text(breakTime);
  }
})

// Add/subtract time to workTime
$('#subtractSessionMinute').click(function(){
  if(workTime > 0) {
    workTime -= 1;
    $('#sessionDisplay').text(workTime);
  }
})

$('#addSessionMinute').click(function(){
  if(workTime < 59) {
    workTime += 1;
    $('#sessionDisplay').text(workTime);
  }
})
```

Comment: It looks like most of your interface is not working (i.e. clicking on + to add more work time is broken but clicking on - sets it to a very large value). I would start from breaking the functionality down and working on smaller parts. To clarify, you want to start the timer, run it for x minutes then start a different timer and run it for y minutes, correct?

Comment: Yes. On clicking start the timer should run the workTime variable. After that hits 0 the clock should clear and then start running the breakTime variable. I'm having trouble clearing the workTime variable and then passing the breakTime variable and starting it.

Comment: The problem here is that you are not separating your concerns correctly. Clearing the time interval effectively destroys that whole function and nothing will happen if you don't set a new interval. Think of this task as this: the clock is either ticking or not, on each tick the value of clock goes down by 1, when the clock reaches 0 it is set to a new value that matches its mode (i.e. break or work), when a clock is stopped the ticking stops - here is a simple [JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yeyamegogu/edit?html,js,console,output) that might help with understanding the logic.